# Quantum mechanics, operators acting on generic state

Tags: operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

For a quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator of constant real mass m and frequency ω, define the
following operators on the Hilbert space:

$ h = a^{+}a     $

$e =   [\sqrt{-1 + a^{+}a}]a^{+} $

$  f = -a\sqrt{-1 + a^{+}a} $

Derive the action of the three operators defined above on a generic state |n>

I dont understand how to obtain the following answers

$ h|n> = n|n> $

e|n> = $\sqrt{(n(n+1)} | n+1 >$

f| n >  = $ -\sqrt{n(n-1)} | n-1> $

Can someone please explain how to obtain these answers? ,cause am looking through my notes and seem pretty confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with the premise that

$$a\left|n\right>=\sqrt{n}\left|n-1\right>\\
a^\dagger\left|n\right>=\sqrt{n+1}\left|n+1\right>$$

we have that the first relation you have is

$$h\left|n\right>=a^\dagger\,a\left|n\right>=\sqrt{n}a\left|n-1\right>=\sqrt{n}\sqrt{(n-1)+1}\left|n-1+1\right>=n\left|n\right>$$

For the second case, you can proceed in the same way

$$ e\left|n\right>=\sqrt{a^\dagger a-1} a^\dagger\left|n\right>=\sqrt{a^\dagger a-1} \sqrt{n+1}\left|n+1\right>$$

Now there comes a kind of tricky part, the square-rooted operators. Luckily (otherwise if this were not the case I'm not sure how to actually proceed), $\left|n+1\right>$ is an eigenvalue of both operators inside the square root, so we have

$$ e\left|n\right>= \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{a^\dagger a-1}\left|n+1\right>= \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1-1}\left|n+1\right>=\sqrt{n(n+1)}\left|n+1\right>$$

Using the same reasoning as above you get the final one, namely

$$ f\left|n\right>=-a\sqrt{a^\dagger a-1}\left|n\right>=-\sqrt{n-1}a\left|n\right>=-\sqrt{n(n+1)}\left|n-1\right>$$